# Blank WebResource.axd

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, webresource.axd

Have a rather large problem.  About two weeks ago I noticed that alert based validation (ValidationSummary) stopped working on my website.  Upon further review, WebResource.axd is coming back blank.  It's not throwing an error, just blank.

I've tried tracing the request via Fiddler and Firebug, and the response is 200 at first. Subsequent cached requests (same page) return 304 (as I would expect).

I've checked IIS configuration, web.config, installed updates, Global.asax, httpHandlers  etc... to try to find out what happened or why it's failing.

I've been troubleshooting this issue for two days now and am running out of options.  Does anyone have any idea what the cause of this could be?  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you check the browser definitions, if you have make them a mess, then they can say to not generate script at all.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a tricky issue, can you check and answer the following two questions:

1. By any chance is debugging enabled on your deployed site.
2. Was the deployed website build properly in release mode?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. Whilst installing John Papa's Hot Towel MVC project into a web forms/MVC hybrid, the routing config does not contain an IgnoreRoute instruction for AXD paths.

This means routing picks up the request ahead of the HttpHandler, and returns a 200 even when no controller exists for the given route pattern - hence a 200 response with an empty body.

I'll pull the bounty but I will upvote Shashank's answer.